# DCOMCnfg "Run application on this computer" is grayed out . WS2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, dcom

I need to select in DCOMCnfg under Location tab following settings: "Run application on this computer" but is greyed out.

It's a Windows Server 2008 R2, 64 bits. I'm logged as administrator. I've opened DCOMcnfg 32 bits.

I leave the link to the image because of my reputation I can't post it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjcEK.png

I've made a virtual machine with similar settings, and it doesn't happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution that has worked for me.

I've created 'Desktop' folder under 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\'. Later I added the user and give it rights.

Then I restarted the DCOMCnfg and it was ok.